# Add and commit all changed files in a branch in gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

I have several files changed in my gitlab branch. Some new and some old. When I add and commit files one by one then on gitlab page only last commit file appear and rest of the changed file do not appear. How to commit them all together so that all of them appear on gitlab.

Answer (score 0):

To add files to the git index changetracker once should use the command [`git add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add)

```
git add -A
```

The -A operator adds all unlisted files

Once added to the index you should commit your files by using [`git commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit)

```
git commit -am "here your message"
```

The [`-a`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---all)

> Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified and deleted, but new files you have not told Git about are not affected.
>   the -m operator is for the message

The [`-m`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---messageltmsggt)

> Use the given  as the commit message. If multiple -m options are given, their values are concatenated as separate paragraphs.

Then you do `git push` to push your items to remote.